# Which is better using array directly or assigning it to a variable and using it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

Consider I have a one mapStateToProps as

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        productList: state.products || []
    }
}
```

And the other one as

```
const EMPTY_ARRAY = []

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        productList: state.products || EMPTY_ARRAY
    }
}
```

Seems that in the latter one re-rendering happens comparatively lesser than the former one.So my question is which is the better way to do and will the latter one will have any side effects if we are using the `EMPTY_ARRAY` at multiple places like

```
const EMPTY_ARRAY = []

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        productList: state.products || EMPTY_ARRAY
        customerList: state.customer || EMPTY_ARRAY
    }
}
```

Since the productList and customerList are referencing the same array?

Comment: This depends on how productList and customerList are used. This is the only thing that matters here, and the question doesn't cover it. *Seems that in the latter one re-rendering happens comparatively lesser than the former one* - please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that shows that.

Comment: Both are used for displaying and can be deleted in immutable way

Comment: Can't imagine a scenario where you would want both of those to share reference to same array

Comment: not to share reference but in case of react context on every call to `mapStateToProps` in the former case it creates a new array reference whereas in the latter one it uses the same array reference, so that reduces unnecessary rerenders

Answer (score 1):

So generally speaking, there are two things going on when you make a variable versus just using empty brackets.

1. You use more memory
2. You take less time

Generally, this is a theme that you will come across a lot when programming, is that it is always balancing memory and speed. In this instance, if you aren't actually storing anything in `EMPTY_ARRAY` then it won't take up much space, and the performance benefits may be worth it.

As far as why you get that speed benefit is because when you put in empty square brackets, the program has to take time to allocate that memory before assigning the result to `productList`, as opposed to just using memory that has already been allocated.

The memory benefit of using the square brackets though is that when your function ends, the garbage collector frees up that memory, making it available for other processes, as opposed to the empty array staying in memory with your constant.

Again, this is something that won't make much of a difference when the variable in question is literally just an empty array, but when you are working on larger scale datasets, this can really make a difference.

Comment: that is fine general programming context but specific to react, since react compares memory reference to detect change so in the latter case the productList and customerList will change only when new data, so this might reduce unnecessary rerender